# Using Transformer for Text-Summarization

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, summarization

I am using huggingface transformer models for **text-summarization**.
Currently I am testing different models such as **T5** and **Pegasus**.
Now these models were trained for summarizing Big Texts into very short like a maximum of two sentences. Now I have the task, that I want summarizations, that are about half the size of the text, ergo the generated summaries are too small for my purpose.

My question now is, if there is a way to tell the model that another sentence came before?
Kind of similar to the logic inside stateful RNNs (although I know they work completly different).
If yes, I could summarize small windows over the sentences always with the information which content came before.

Is that just a thing of my mind? I cant believe that I am the only one, who wants to create shorter summaries, but not only 1 or two sentence long ones.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not transfer learning? Train them on your specific texts and summaries.

I trained T5 on specific limited text over 5 epoch and got very good results. I adopted the code from here to my needs https://github.com/patil-suraj/exploring-T5/blob/master/t5_fine_tuning.ipynb

Let me know if you have a specific training questions.

Comment: But can you transfer learn with more than the original sequence length limitation?

Comment: Yes you can. If 512 does not suite you can change it as per google documentation:


"You can also use a different batch size for fine-tuning. We set the batch size according to the total number of tokens in a batch. By default, a batch uses a sequence length of 512."

source:

https://github.com/google-research/text-to-text-transfer-transformer/blob/master/README.md#fine-tuning

Comment: Thanks then, I will have a look at your nb!

Comment: @BobbyDonchev How would you export the trained model for future inferences after deployment. For example in `Keras`, it can be done as exporting to `.h5` and then the regular workflow.